# Impact Analysis in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Impact analysis for a ruby on rails application. Is it possible? And is there tools which can make this achievable? I have a really big application. I want to check the impact of the changes made in application, so that am aware of the bugs which can be raised in the application. Please say your suggestions, if there is any way to measure the impact.

Comment: There is no way to accurately measure the impact in all cases (thanks to all the dynamism). A comprehensive test suite is your best ally here.